# Blackberry changePassword not working on openfire

Tags: blackberry

I am using below code to change password of login user on openfire but this returns nullpointer exception.

I have taken the reference from the below link:

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html#usecases-changepw

```
        if(use_ssl){
            final SecureConnection sc = (SecureConnection) Connector.open("ssl://" + this.server + ":" + this.port+this.connectionMask, Connector.READ_WRITE);
            is = sc.openInputStream();
            os = sc.openOutputStream();
            this.reader = new XmlReader(is);
            this.writer = new XmlWriter(os);

            try{
                String stream="<stream:stream to='204.93.197.136' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>";
                os.write(stream.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                do {
                    reader.next();
                } while ((reader.getType() != XmlReader.END_TAG) || (!reader.getName().equals("stream:features")));

                for (Enumeration enu = listeners.elements(); enu.hasMoreElements();) {
                    XmppListener xl = (XmppListener) enu.nextElement();
                }   

                String sendRequest="<iq type='set' to='204.93.197.136' id='change1'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'><username>"+Jxa.loginUserName+"</username><password>"+newPassword+"</password></query></iq>"; 
                os.write(sendRequest.getBytes());
                os.flush();

                int count=0;
                do {
                    reader.next();
                    if(reader.getName().equals("error")){
                        count++;    
                    }
                } while ((reader.getType() != XmlReader.END_TAG) || (!reader.getName().equals("iq")));
                for (Enumeration enu = listeners.elements(); enu.hasMoreElements();) {
                    XmppListener xl = (XmppListener) enu.nextElement();
                }   
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        Dialog.alert("Record Not Updated");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> but this returns nullpointer exception.

You need to figure out what is causing the NullPointerException. Stepping through the code in a debugger will likely reveal what line is hitting the exception. Then you can look for a null value in your sample code that shouldn't be null.  The next challenge is to figure out what value is expected, besides 'null'

Alternatively, you can reason about what is happening in the sample code, without running it at all. This typically gives you better understanding of what it is doing, but can be time consuming.

Comment: Hello Micheal i m getting NullPointerException because my XMlparser class is not getting any <password> tag in request,response.So could you tell me how to changepassword on openfire server.